# HasAndBelongsToMany relations in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I am trying to  go through the example mention in the documentation for the HasAndBelongsToMany relations. 
[Documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/HasAndBelongsToMany-relations.html)

For the Assembly and Parts example, the documentation says, it adds a function which can add part to assembly.

```
assembly.parts.add(part,
  function(err) {
  ...
});
```

But this adds only a single part to assembly. If I have to add multiple parts, do we have a function for that? I think calling this function in a loop multiple times is not an optimal way to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to add multiple items at once. There seems to be a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40606502/6279370). This might help you.